# mysql transaction in stored procedure (locking/rollback)

Tags: mysql

does a transaction in a stored procedure do any locking to prevent others from updating tables?

also do i need to explicitly put in rollback logic or will the transaction automatically roll back if an error occurs because it never reaches the commit command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does a transaction in a stored procedure do any locking to prevent others from updating tables?

When you perform some `DML` on an `InnoDB` table, the rows affected get locked until the end of transaction (doesn't matter is it inside a stored procedure or not).

You can modify the locked rows inside the same transaction that locked it.

To explicitly lock some rows, issue:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   condition
FOR UPDATE
```

Except for commiting or rolling back the transaction, there is no other way to unlock the rows

> Do i need to explicitly put in rollback logic or will the transaction automatically roll back if an error occurs because it never reaches the commit command.

You'll need to perform a rollback explicitly.

Comment: i guess what i'm asking is will the rows stay locked for the duration of the transaction.  meaning if i have multiple updates will the lock be released after each update or only after all the updates are complete because they are in a transaction.

Comment: The lock will retain until the end of the transaction, that's the whole point of locking :)